# I am implementing lz77 compression for images. But if I insert an RGB image the output is wrong could any of you help me?

Tags: python, rgb, lz77

****when i insert a grayscale image then the algorithm works if i insert a rgb image the output is wrong.
is the way I work with the rgb image correct? I don't understand why can someone help me?****

**library used**

```
from PIL import Image
```

import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2

```
 def lz77Compress (image,sw,lab):
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    print("Initial size", img)
    flat = np.array(img).flatten()
    #cv2.imshow("input", img)
    row = img.shape[0]
    col = img.shape[1]
    tot = row * col
    slidingWindows = sw
    lookAhead = lab
```

**array of tuyple and charactert**

```
encodedTuple = np.array([]) 
encodedChar = np.array([])
```

**pointer in the search buffer**

```
sbPointer = 0
while sbSize + sbPointer < tot :
    max_match = 0
    max_match_go_back = 0        
    selChar = sbPointer + sbSize
```

**empty sequence**

```
   seqY = np.array([])
    for i in range(sbPointer,sbPointer + sbSize):
        if(flat[i] == encodeCharacters):
            seqY = np.append(seqY,i)
```

**check if there is a match in the lookAheadBuffer**

```
 if(seqY.size == 0 ):
        encodedTuple = np.append(encodedTuple,(0,0))
        encodedChar = np.append (encodedChar,encodeCharacters)
    else:

        for j in seqY:
        #lunghezza della corrispodenza
            matchLenght= 0
            returnBack = selChar -i
            it = 0 
            while selChar + it < tot :
                if flat[it + j] == flat[selChar + it]:
                    matchLenght +=1
                    it +=1
              # se non trova corrispondenze
                else: 
                    break
            if matchLenght>max_match:
               max_match = matchLenght
               returnBack = max_match_go_back
```

**save corrispondence and tuple in array**

```
encodedTuple = np.append(encodedTuple,(max_match_go_back,max_match))
encodedChar = np.append(encodedChar,flat[selChar + max_match - 1])
        
       sbPointer+= 1 +max_match
```

**save of encodedTuple, encodedChar , file compresses.txt and imsize of decompression **

```
print("Prova", encodedTuple, encodedChar)
print("ArrayBin",encodedTuple.tolist(), encodedChar.tolist())
np.save("encodedTuple", encodedTuple) 
np.save("encodedChar", encodedChar)
a = encodedTuple.tolist()
b = encodedChar.tolist()
c= (a,b)
print("File compresso in : Copressed.txt")
output = open("Compressed.txt","w+")
output.write(str(c))
imgSize = open('imgSize.txt', "w")
imgSize.write(str(row) + '\n')  # write row dimension
imgSize.write(str(col) + '\n')  # write col dimension
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Main **

```
path = "./im3.jpg"
```

lz77Compress (path,500,500)

Comment: RGB image has 3 channels (in most cases). Try adding `ch = img.shape[2]` after `col = img.shape[1]` and `tot = row * col * ch`. Or better: `tot = img.size`. In case it's not the problem, please post a code sample that reproduces the problem - a code that someone can copy, paste and execute.

Comment: i added ch but now I have this probelm :  File "c:/Users/anton/Desktop/Progetto/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    lz77Compress (path,500,500)
  File "c:\Users\anton\Desktop\Progetto\image.py", line 35, in lz77Compress
    encodeCharacters = flat[selChar]
IndexError: index 206 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 206

Comment: I case you decide to post a code that I can actually execute, please let me know.

Comment: @Rotem in the comment i can't poste the code because is long, i give you my link github github.com/Anto-9393/project-multimedia-lz77. Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, RGB image has 3 color channels, and gray image has 1 color channel.

- Assume `img` is a NumPy array that represents a gray image:
  `img.shape` is going to be `(rows, cols)`, and `img.size` is `rows`*`cols`.
- Assume `img` is a NumPy array that represents a RGB (or BGR) image:
  `img.shape` is going to be `(rows, cols, ch)`, and `img.size` is `rows`*`cols`*`ch`.
  In case of RGB, `ch` = 3.

I downloaded your code from [github](http://github.com/Anto-9393/project-multimedia-lz77).
I saw you already corrected the code to support RGB images.

I can't reproduce the error in line 35 of image.py
Did you fix it?

The issues I could find:

- You are not closing the files:
  Close the files at the end of `lz77Compress`:

  ```
   # We must close the files.
   output.close()
   imgSize.close()
  ```

You better also close `imsize` after reading `row`, `col`, `ch` in `lz77Decompressor`.

- When using `cv2.imshow("output", decodeArray)`, you need the type of `decodeArray` to be `uint8`.
  You may use the following code to show the output:

  ```
   cv2.imshow("output", decodeArray.astype(np.uint8)) # Show as uint8
  ```

In case you want to support both gray and RGB, you can check if `len(img.shape)` is `2` or `3`, and add some logic at the Decompressor.

Note:
I didn't review the entire code, so there might be problems that I missed.

Comment: first of all I would like to thank you for your suggestions. I solved it but now I have a problem regarding the compression speed. With small images (205,204) the algorithm takes 1 minute instead with larger images the time increases a lot. How could I optimize the code? p.s are just starting out with python.

Comment: When I need something to run fast, I use C and not Python. Loops in Python are very slow, so try to avoid long loops, when possible. Check your implementation to see if there are loops you can avoid. I don't know if it's relevant, but try to use vectorized operations (using NumPy) when adequate. If you can't avoid using loops, you may try [Cython](https://cython.org/) and/or [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). Please note that my Python experience is limited.

Comment: https://github.com/Anto-9393/project-multimedia-lz77  I made some changes, the algorithm has speeded up but now the final image is only half visible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well...
I know it's hard, but you will have to debug your code.

Comment: @ Rotem : could you tell me why I have this problem in this algorithm?  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67043929/valueerror-cannot-reshape-array-of-size-1-into-shape-500-700-3